# Python 2.7 pyodbc or pymssql vs R RODBC

Tags: performance, python-2.7, pandas, pyodbc, pymssql

I'm trying to migrate R code to Python 2.7 in order to compare both. The first problem I get is when I try to do an odbc connection. R is much faster than python, but since I'm a newbie in Python I'm not sure if I'm using the right package.

In R I write:

```
ptm <- proc.time()
require(RODBC)
dbXX <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};
    server=s001111;database=XX;trusted_connection=true')
rech<-sqlQuery(dbXX, "select top 10000* from XX.dbo.table ", as.is=T)
proc.time() - ptm
```

and I get:

```
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   2.47    0.11    2.87
```

I have downloaded Anaconda for python 2.7 windows 7 64. 
So in Spyder I write:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
from pandas.io.sql import read_frame
sql = 'select top 10000 * from XX.dbo.table'
cnn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=s001111;DATABASE=XX;Trusted_Connection=yes')

start = time.time()
data=pd.read_sql(sql,cnn)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

This takes 6.35 secs

I've also tried with pymssql:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='s001111', database='XX')  
start = time.time()
data=pd.read_sql(sql,conn)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

This takes 38.3 secs!

The real query needs to read a table which dimension is  220.000 rows by 353 columns and apply a filter (with where).

I only need to **extract** data from the db.

Is there a way to do it faster in Python 2.7?

I've found [pyodbc-memory usage relation caused by SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766178/manage-pyodbc-memory-usage) but I guess that if it were an SQL problem would be doing the same in R, wouldn't it?

I've also found this: [IOPro](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/faster-more-memory-efficient-sql-queries-iopro) but it's not free!

At this point I was wondering if the problem was the ODBC connection or pandas itself, so I tried:

```
cur = conn.cursor();
start = time.time()
cur.execute(sql);
tabla=cur.fetchall() 
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

But it took 29.29 secs.

**So, still: how is it possible that R is much faster than Python to retrieve data from an SQL Microsoft DB?**

Comment: The performance can be very dependent on the driver you are using. I would suggest to try out another driver to see if this performs better. Eg alternative is ``pymssql`` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.1). See also the list here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/mssql.html

Comment: Further, small note: `read_frame` is deprecated, you should use `pd.read_sql` instead. I also recommend to use `SQLAlchemy` to specify the connection (but this is independent from the driver you are using). See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Comment: @joris thanks! I've downloaded with conda pymssql. Also wrote the code and ran it. How can I measure the time that requires each library? I think that still it's taking much more time than R code... is this possible?

Comment: ok with import time (I've done it) takes much more time than R time.time()

Comment: That is certainly possible. If you are using IPython, you can time how long a command takes using `%time` (eg `%time pd.read_sql(...)`)

Comment: If you want to test if the problem is pyodbc or pandas itself, you can time how long the query itself takes, by timing `cur = conn.cursor(); cur.execute(sql); cur.fetchall()` and compare it to the timing of fetching this query with pandas

Comment: thanks @joris, but still takes much time. Is this possible?

Comment: That is certainly possible, that would just mean that the most time taken lies with pyodbc, not with pandas (which is what I would expect, as it is pyodbc that does the actual reading from the database into python objects). But, you showed that reading it with read_sql takes 6.35 s using pyodbc, so reading it with a raw execute shouldn't take longer. Further, what version of pymssql are you using?

Comment: Well I've done the same test. I've selected the top 10000 rows from a table (of 3740224 records) and the the execution time with pymssql was 0.269999980927 sec which is not so bad I guess. So there is no issue neither with pymmsql nor with python

Answer (score 3):

Both RODBC and pyodbc will probably spend most of their time transferring data from the database server to the local computer you use to run your query. A very important parameter here is the number of rows moved from db server to local computer for each fetch loop. Both RODBC and pyodbc let you to configure this parameter.

Now, if you want to compare apples with apples:

1. use the same infrastructure: same remote db, same local client, same network in between
2. use the same ODBC layer: same driver manager, same driver, same DSN
3. retrieve **exactly** the same number of rows for each fetch loop with both R and python. **Be aware**: if you don't say anything RODBC's sqlQuery() will fetch 100 rows at a time!

I did use this approach to compare RODBC and pyodbc with three different database (not including SQL Server) and I always find the performances to be comparable.

Here is the R code:

```
library(RODBC)
ch <- odbcConnect("DWN",uid="xyz",pwd="xyz",rows_at_time=1024);
ds <- sqlQuery(ch,"select * from large_table limit 100000");
```

And here you have the python code:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> ch = pyodbc.connect('DSN=xyz;UID=xyz;PWD=xyz')
>>> curs = ch.cursor()
>>> curs.execute("select * from large_table limit 100000")
>>> while True:
...      rows = curs.fetchmany(1024)
...      if not rows:
...          break
... 
>>>
```